# immutableJS - updateIn method doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a map like this structure in immutable js:

```
myMap = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: [
                { d: "something1", ... },
                { d: "something2", ... }
            ],
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Then I want to update the value of `d`s.

I've tried like:

```
myMap.updateIn(["a", "b", "c"], (each) => {
    each.set("d", "something else");
});
```

and like:

```
myMap.updateIn(["a", "b", "c"], (each) => {
    each.map((e) => {
        e.set("d", "something else");
    });
});
```

But as you know, those does not work.

How can I update the value of `d`s?

Comment: the last code fragment looks good to me. I would say that this should work.

Comment: @JoshuaK No it doesnt work to me :( Could you try that? When I tried the second one, the value of `myMap` was not changed.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it. It works. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/1qr7pdre/)

Comment: @JoshuaK Your code works well, but my code above doesn't. Finally, I find the reason. That's because of `{}` in my code.

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yonggoonoh/y8nzwvm0/2/) is my wrong code.

Comment: oh the missing return. I'm so sorry. I just oversaw it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason why my code above doesn't work.

Firstly, the second code is **partially** correct, but first one is wrong.

The **partially** means that the logic was correct, but the grammar of ES6 was not.

So, the correct code is:

```
const updatedMyMap = myMap.updateIn(["a", "b", "c"], each => 
    each.map(e => e.set("d", "something else"))
);
```

In [arrow function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => **{ statements }**
>
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => **expression**
>
> // equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => **{ return expression; }**

this is why my code didn't work.

I should have returned the result of `map()`.